# Django-rest-framework IF statement in post method is not executing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**(I will provide full code at the bottom)**

I am trying to create an API view with django rest framework. I wanted to create a login API so I was first testing out on how to check if a data exists in a field in the database. Here are the "fields = values" that I want to check that actually exists in the database:

- `pengerja_id` = 123 ***//correct data***
- `password` = 123

Now for example I want to try inputting the wrong value:

- `pengerja_id` = 555 ***//wrong data***
- `password` = 555

Now, I run an `if queryset.exists()` statement. Whenever I gave `pengerja_id` a **wrong** value like '555' it executes the `else` statement as `queryset` returns `false`. But whenever I gave it the **correct** value of '123', It fails to execute the **WHOLE** code for some reason starting from if `serializer.is_valid()`.

Here is the code inside **view.py**

```
class AuthorizeMemberView(APIView):
    serializer_class = AuthorizeMemberSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            pengerja_id = serializer.data.get('pengerja_id')
            password = serializer.data.get('password')
            print(f'pengerja_id={pengerja_id}, password={password}')
            
            queryset = COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER.objects.filter(pengerja_id = pengerja_id)

            if queryset.exists():
                return Response({'Success':'User Verified'}, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
            else:
                return Response({'Login Failed':'User not registered'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
            
        return Response({'Bad request':'Data failed to submit'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is the code inside **serializers.py**

```
class AuthorizeMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER
        fields = ('pengerja_id', 'password')
```

The results are whenever I entered '123' it gives me the `HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST`. Whenever I entered something else for example '555', it gives me the `HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND` response which means the `else` statement works.

This is what I've tried so far:

First is to print out to check which block of code that isn't executed when I passed in the correct value of pengerja_id = '123' from my database.

```
class AuthorizeMemberView(APIView):
    serializer_class = AuthorizeMemberSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(f'serializer_class={self.serializer_class}') # this is executed
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(serializer.is_valid()) # this is not executed
            pengerja_id = str(serializer.data.get('pengerja_id'))
            password = serializer.data.get('password')
            print(f'pengerja_id={pengerja_id}, password={password}')
            
            queryset = COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER.objects.filter(pengerja_id = pengerja_id)
            print('Checking queryset exists()')
            print(queryset.query)
            if queryset.exists():
                print("User Verified")
                return Response({'Success':'User Verified'}, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
            else:
                print('not found')
                return Response({'Login Failed':'User not registered'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
            
        return Response({'Bad request':'Data failed to submit'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Everything from `print(serializer.is_valid())` below is not executed. But if I gave in the value of '555'(wrong value) everything is executed until return `Response({'Login Failed':'User not registered'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)`.

Here is the output in the terminal.

[Value of anything else other than '123' output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIKSG.png)

[Value of '123' ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9OCW.png)

So what went wrong here? Is it some kind of bug that django has or am I missing something here?

**This is the full code below**

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import mysql.connector

# Create your models here.
class COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER(models.Model):
    pengerja_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    nomor_telepon = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nama_cool = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tempat_lahir = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tanggal_lahir = models.DateField(null=True)
    status_pekerjaan = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    domisili = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user_session_key = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER

class ShowMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER
        fields = ('pengerja_id','nomor_telepon','password','nama_cool','tempat_lahir',
                  'tanggal_lahir', 'status_pekerjaan', 'domisili', 'user_session_key')

class InsertNewMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER
        fields = ('pengerja_id','nomor_telepon','password')
                #   ,'nama_cool','tempat_lahir',
                #   'tanggal_lahir', 'status_pekerjaan', 'domisili')

class AuthorizeMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER
        fields = ('pengerja_id', 'password')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from rest_framework import generics, status
from .serializers import ( 
                    ShowMemberSerializer,
                    InsertNewMemberSerializer,
                    AuthorizeMemberSerializer
                    )
from .models import COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

# Create your views here.
# def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
#     return render(request, index.html)

class ShowMemberView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShowMemberSerializer

class InsertNewMemberView(APIView):
    serializer_class = InsertNewMemberSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            pengerja_id = serializer.data.get('pengerja_id')
            nomor_telepon = serializer.data.get('nomor_telepon')
            password = serializer.data.get('password')

            queryset = COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER.objects.filter(pengerja_id = pengerja_id)
            if not queryset.exists():
                db = COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER(
                    pengerja_id = pengerja_id,
                    nomor_telepon = nomor_telepon,
                    password = password,
                )
                # db.nama_cool = ''
                # db.tempat_lahir = ''
                # db.tanggal_lahir = ''
                # db.status_pekerjaan = ''
                # db.domisili =''
                db.save()
                return Response(ShowMemberSerializer(db).data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
            else:
                return Response({'Bad request':'Data failed to submit'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
        return Response({'Bad request':'Page not valid'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class AuthorizeMemberView(APIView):
    serializer_class = AuthorizeMemberSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(f'serializer_class={self.serializer_class}')
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(serializer.is_valid())
            pengerja_id = str(serializer.data.get('pengerja_id'))
            password = serializer.data.get('password')
            print(f'pengerja_id={pengerja_id}, password={password}')
            
            queryset = COOL_YOUTH_MEMBER.objects.filter(pengerja_id = pengerja_id)
            print('Checking queryset exists()')
            print(queryset.query)
            if queryset.exists():
                print("User Verified")
                # db = queryset[0]
                # db.pengerja_id = pengerja_id
                # db.password = password
                return Response({'Success':'User Verified'}, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
            else:
                print('not found')
                return Response({'Login Failed':'User not registered'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
            
        return Response({'Bad request':'Data failed to submit'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
                ShowMemberView,
                InsertNewMemberView,
                AuthorizeMemberView,
                )

urlpatterns = [
    path('show', ShowMemberView.as_view()),
    path('new-member', InsertNewMemberView.as_view()),
    path('authorize', AuthorizeMemberView.as_view()),
]
```

Also the class `InsertNewMemberView` works just fine. Code is almost the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `if serializer.is_valid()` try this to know what the error is:

```py
print(serialzer.errors)
```

It will return a dictionary with the errors

Comment: It showed {'pengerja_id': [ErrorDetail(string='coo l_yout h_member with this pengerja id already exists.', code='unique')]}. I guess it thought I was trying to make a new post request with an already existing 'pengerja_id'. All I tried doing was check to see if the data exists, not update the field. Guess I'll have to modify my code.